# Dynamically resizing a struct in C

Tags: c, struct

I'm fiddling around with Object oriented programming in C (note! Not C++ or C# - just plain ol' C).  Right now, I'm trying to dynamically resize a struct (I'm playing with writing a simple String class).  The code builds okay:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct TestClass 
{
    char *s;
    size_t size;
    size_t b_size;
    void (*CreateString) (struct TestClass*,char*);
};

void TestClassCreateString(struct TestClass *m, char* str) 
{
    char *buf;
    m->size = strlen(str);

    if (!m->size) 
    {
        free(m->s);
        m->s = malloc(16);
    } 
    else 
    {
        buf = realloc(m->s, m->size);
        if (buf) m->s = buf;
    }
}

struct TestClass* TestClassCreate() 
{
    struct TestClass* m = malloc((sizeof(struct TestClass)));
    m->CreateString = TestClassCreateString;
    return m;
}

int main() 
{
    struct TestClass* fizz = TestClassCreate();
    fizz->CreateString(fizz,"Hello World");
    free(fizz);
    return 0;
}
```

…But on running it I get the following error:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x5000000000000000: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Is anyone able to identify where I've gone wrong?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a `struct TestClass` in `TestClassCreate()` the code misses to properly initialise the freshly allocated `struct`.

So calling

```
    free(m->s);
```

tries to free memory at a random address, which invokes undefined behaviour and typically crashes the program.

To fix this modify the code as follows

```
struct TestClass* TestClassCreate() 
{
  struct TestClass* m = ...

  ...

  m->s = NULL;
  m->size = 0;
  m->b_size = 0;

  return m;
}
```

To make things better also add some error checking:

```
struct TestClass* TestClassCreate() 
{
  struct TestClass * m = malloc((sizeof(struct TestClass)));

  if (NULL != m)
  {
    m->CreateString = TestClassCreateString;
    m->s = NULL;
    m->size = 0;
    m->b_size = 0;
  }

  return m;
}
```

To make the code even more fail-safe apply these last changes:

```
struct TestClass* TestClassCreate(void) 
{
  struct TestClass * m = malloc(sizeof *m);

  ...
```

---

Further more the code misses to allocate memory for the C-"string"'s `0`-terminator here:

```
void TestClassCreateString(struct TestClass *m, char* str) 
{

  ...
  else 
  {
    buf = realloc(m->s, m->size + 1); /* allocate 1 byte more for the trailing 
                                       `0` marking the end of a C-"string". */
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

`malloc` does not zero its memory; it returns garbage, so you get an invalid pointer inside this `struct`:

```
struct TestClass* m = malloc((sizeof(struct TestClass)));
```

Comment: I don't understand what You mean? It gives rubbish ok, but he is not using pointer `CreateString` before assigning to it. He assigns pointer to the function just after `malloc`

Comment: @DawidPi: I'm talking about `s`, not `CreateString`.

Answer (score 1):

You are short by `1-byte`. You need to add `1` to `m->size` for the null-terminator if you intend to copy `str` to `m->s`. E.g.:

```
void TestClassCreateString(struct TestClass *m, char* str) 
{
    char *buf;
    m->size = strlen(str);

    if (!m->size) 
    {
        free(m->s);
        m->s = malloc(16);
    } 
    else 
    {
        buf = realloc(m->s, m->size + 1);
        if (buf) m->s = buf;
        strncpy (m->s, str, m->size + 1);
    }
}
```

Then you can do something like:

```
int main() 
{
    struct TestClass* fizz = TestClassCreate();
    fizz->CreateString(fizz,"Hello World");
    printf ("\n fizz->s : %s\n\n", fizz->s);
    free(fizz);
    return 0;
}
```

and get:

```
$ ./bin/oo_struct

 fizz->s : Hello World
```